# MYSQL Error 1054 (42S22): Unknown column in 'where clause'

Tags: mysql, python-3.x

This is the script that I am calling to get the phone_number based on user_name via python using mysql

```
def get_number_based_on_phone( username):
    """get the username based on number"""

    sql = 'SELECT phone_number from user_data_base WHERE `user_name` = %s' % (username)
    db = dbq()
    phone_number = db.getFieldValue(sql)

    return phone_number


class dbq:

    def __init__(self):
        self._conn = mysql.connector.connect(user='xxx', password='xxx', host='127.0.0.1', database='users')

        self._cursor = self._conn.cursor(buffered=True)

    def closeConn(self):
        self._cursor.close()
        self._conn.close()

    def db_query(self, sql):
        self._cursor.execute(sql)
        rows = self._cursor.fetchall()
        df = DataFrame(rows, columns=self._cursor.column_names)
        return df

    def getFieldValue(self, sql):
        try:
            self._cursor.execute(sql)
            row = self._cursor.fetchone()
            if row is None:
                qid_value = ""
            else:
                if row[0] is None:
                    qid_value = ""
                else:
                    qid_value = str(row[0])
            return qid_value
        except Error as error:
            print(error)
        finally:
            self._cursor.close()
            self._conn.close()
```

When I call the function:

```
 get_number_based_on_phone("ODIN")
```

The error message that I got is

```
1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'odin' in 'where clause'
```

If I dont pass username as a variable but just call it as a regular query in mysql, there doesn't seem to be any problem. "ODIN" is one of the username in the database

Comment: i am nerly sure that you must quote the %s else Mysql take this argument as fieldname

Comment: is there a goog cause why you don't use execute and fetchall?

Comment: @BerndBuffen comment is correct. But the way you are handling this is in a word, terrible. You are leaving yourself open to a SQL Injection attack. If you do not know what that is, you should Google the subject right away. The  bottom line is you should be using *prepared statements*. It would look like `cursor.execute('SELECT phone_number from user_data_base WHERE user_name = %s', [username])`. You are not putting quotes around `%s`, which are serving as placeholders for the actual values which passed in a list or tuple as the second parameter to `execute`.